# How to align the pictures horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i just want to know how to align this pictures horizontally because the aligned vertically i just want to align in horizontally thankyou guys

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .container {
   position: relative;
   width: 20%;
 }

 .image {
   opacity: 1;
   display: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: auto;
   transition: .5s ease;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
 }

 .middle {
   transition: .5s ease;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 3%;
   transform: translate(0%, -20%);
   -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
   text-align: center;
 }

 .container:hover .image {
   opacity: 0.5;
 }

 .container:hover .middle {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .text {
   background-color: #dbe0dc;
   color: black;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
 }
 .column {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 5px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-375-456327.png" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Avatar sample</div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="container">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREEGUm8xTq6g_39HvAO-LDynq64MqzfEyHenC3E5Sz0Ci5DWck" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Avatar sample 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `display: inline` on `container` and `text-align: center` on `body`...

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: sorry accidentally put javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

- added `text-align: center` to body
- removed `position: absolute` and `width: 50%` from .image
- added `display: block` and `max-width: 50%` to .image
- added `display: inline-block` to .container

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translate(0%, -20%);
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #dbe0dc;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-375-456327.png" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Avatar sample</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREEGUm8xTq6g_39HvAO-LDynq64MqzfEyHenC3E5Sz0Ci5DWck" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Avatar sample 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: **Important sidenote**: Depending on your total project. You probably want to **delete** the `body {text-align: center}`. If you add `margin: auto` to `.image` instead, the images will be centered inside their respective columns.

Answer (score 1):

Add float: left; in container class as like below, it will work....

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code, This code work perfectly

CSS :

```
        img {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .container {
          position: relative;
          width: 20%;
        }

        .image {
          opacity: 1;
          display: absolute;
          width: 50%;
          height: auto;
          transition: .5s ease;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .middle {
          transition: .5s ease;
          opacity: 0;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 3%;
          transform: translate(0%, -20%);
          -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
          text-align: center;
        }

        .container:hover .image {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .container:hover .middle {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        .text {
          background-color: #dbe0dc;
          color: black;
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 10px 20px;
        }
        .column {
          float: left;
          width: 33.33%;
          padding: 5px;
        }

    }

    body ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-375-456327.png" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">Avatar sample</div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREEGUm8xTq6g_39HvAO-LDynq64MqzfEyHenC3E5Sz0Ci5DWck" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">Avatar sample</div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run into trouble using floats. The easiest way to do it is to add another container around everything and then use flexbox.

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-container">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/avatar-375-456327.png" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">Avatar sample</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREEGUm8xTq6g_39HvAO-LDynq64MqzfEyHenC3E5Sz0Ci5DWck" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">Avatar sample 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon-container {
  display: flex;
}
```